# Transparent iphone application

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiview, uiwindow

I'm trying to build an application that is launched has a transparent background, in practice, showing only the objects in view (buttons, labels etc etc) but not the background so you can see the background the user's home.
In the example file you can see the purple square image at the center of the screen, in theory should be a normal UIView with a picture in the center but does not see the background of UIWindow/UIView.

Is possible to realize such a thing? Can anyone help me?

thanks

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you cant do this with the official API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible, try setting the window background color to clear, as well as the view controller's view background color.

I say it might be possible because I've seen my home screen while using some apps, for example, the Facebook app sometimes shows it during a transition (it might be a bug on either Facebook or the OS).

Anyway, I'm pretty sure that kind of app would be rejected from the App Store, so be advised.

Comment: i have try but don't work, if i set UIWindow clearcolor and viewcontroller.view clearcolor when i start application background is black.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then I guess it's not possible at all. It was a long shot anyway.

Answer (score 2):

No. It's not possible using the official SDK. I'm interested to know why you would want to do this?

Comment: because the effect that resulted I liked for my app, alternatively one could not draw a screenshot of the screen when launching the app and set a UIImage background of my UIView with the captured image?

Comment: Yes, but I doubt apple would like this in their review process. I would imagine you would be rejected.