# How to make transparent background see the home screen?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transparent iphone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514376/transparent-iphone-application)

I want to do an app in which user can see the home screen, meaning the screen where that app icon is present.  Can anyone can tell how to do this?  I have tried to do that by setting:

```
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
self.view.opaque=NO;
```

But it's not showing the transparent screen. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Interesting, but I doubt that this is possible at all.

Comment: nhahtdh is correct. You can only make your Apps home screen visible. Not your phone home screen.

Comment: Definitely great idea if successful but if successful some one will surely shocked to see why my home screen is not touchable or scrollable.and after some time he realize ohhh, I forgot one application is running.

Comment: r u try to set window.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
plz check this

Comment: Ayaz , I tried but its not working.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible with official SDK..

EDIT : Oops after some searching it seems like this question is a duplicate of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514376/transparent-iphone-application)..

Answer (score 1):

You can add image to window in your appDelegate

```
UIImage* bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
UIImageView* bgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:bgImage];
[self.window addSubview:bgView];
[bgView release];
```

and then you can set all view's background as per your requirement by default it is clearColor

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:100 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.1]]; // for red transparent


[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:100 blue:0 alpha:0.1]]; // for green transparent


[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:100 alpha:0.1]]; // for blue transparent
```